# Passing data from child to parent component not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am passing data from my child component (Header component) to my parent component (App component). My idea: when I click on my creating button in header component I want to send information to app component to hide header and footer. Here is code example.

Header.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class Header extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showHeaderAndFooter: false
    };
}

onChangeChildComponent = () => {
    this.props.changeVisibilityOfHeaderAndFooter(this.state.showHeaderAndFooter);
}

render() {
    return (  
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Button href="/createGym" onClick={this.onChangeChildComponent.bind(this)}> Create </Button>
            </Nav>           
        </Navbar>
    );
}
}
```

export default Header;

App.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './components/header';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './components/home';
import CreateGym from './components/create-gym';
import Login from './components/authentication/login';

class App extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        showHeaderAndFooter: true
    };
}

onChangeChildComponent (showHeaderAndFooter) {
    this.setState(
    {
        showHeaderAndFooter: showHeaderAndFooter
    });
}

Container = () => (
  <div>
      { this.state.showHeaderAndFooter && 
      <Header 
         changeVisibilityOfHeaderAndFooter = {this.onChangeChildComponent.bind(this)}
      />
      } 
      <div className="container">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path="/createGym" component={CreateGym} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </div>
      { this.state.showHeaderAndFooter && <Footer /> } 
  </div>
  )

render() {
    console.log(this.state.showHeaderAndFooter);
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Fragment>
                    { <Route component={this.Container}/> }
                </Fragment>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>  
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

The problem is because my code is entering App constructor twice. At the first time, everything is fine, but on the second time, this boolean showHeaderAndFooter is again set to true because that is the default value. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't be passing from child > parent. react is uni-directional (that means data can only flow in one way, and that way is downwards)

to achieve this, move the state into the parent

```
class Parent extends React = {
   this.state = { showHeaderAndFooter: false }

   functionToToggleShowing = () => {
      this.setState({showHeaderAndFooter: !this.state.showHeaderAndFooter})
   }

  render() {
    return(
        <Child showHeaderAndFooter={this.state.showHeaderAndFooter} functionToToggleShowing={functionToToggleShowing} />
    )
  } 

}
```

that is pseduo code but essentially move the state to the parent and pass down the state to the child as well as a way to change that state

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my code like this, but the result is same. When I click on my "Create" button, this boolean showHeaderAndFooter is set to false, but after that, it again change the value to true. It seems like App.js override that value to true again. I don't know why... Maybe is the problem in some other file, I don't know.

Comment: @Nemanja I would comment out all `setStates` and then slowly comment them back in to identify where the misbehaviour is happening

Answer (score 1):

React allows passing of control from child to parent by means of props.

**Here is the 3-step procedure to make it work:**

**Step 1:**  Create a data member in Parent, which manipulates parent state.

**Step 2:** Send the parent's data member as a prop to the child.

**Step 3:**  In the child, Call the prop sent by parent for responding to an event.

**Here is a demonstration of passing control from child to parent, using the above technique:**

The example has 2 components -

- Parent component is **App.jsx**
- Child component is **Header.jsx**

Parent has a state-manipulating data member called '***hideHeader***'.

Parent passes ***hideHeader*** as a prop called ***onClick*** to the child.

Child calls the prop sent by parent, in  response to its ***onClick*** event.

**Parent component - App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from "./Header";

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showHeader: true
    }
  }


  {/*  A state-manipulating data member */}

  hideHeader = () => {
    this.setState({showHeader: false})
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        {/* State-manipulating data member sent as prop to child */}

        { this.state.showHeader &&
            <Header onClick={this.hideHeader} />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child component - Header.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Header Demo</h1>

        {/* Call the prop sent by parent when button is clicked */}

        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hide</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Output:**

**Before 'Hide' button is clicked:**

[image]

**After 'Hide' button is clicked:**

[image]

Comment: I can see that your code is working, but still strange behaviour in my project... render method in App.js is firing 4 times! it is so strange. First two times it is ok, showHeader is false, but at other two times, it is true again, and I can still see header in my project. So, I assume that my problem is on another place... It is not about parent/child data transfering...